# MERGE seems to return constraint violation on matched rows instead of ignoring

Tags: sql, oracle11g

**SOLVED: The SELECT within the USING did indeed generate duplicate s_main_obj_id. I thought they must be unique (uuids, but generated with a stupid tweak), however when you've eliminated the impossible... ;-)**

Using Oracle 11g (not R2), I want to merge some values from a source table s into a target table t. The PK of both s and t is a field obj_id.

I use:

```
MERGE 
    INTO target_table t
    USING (SELECT  ... AS s_main_obj_id, ... AS s_p1, 
           ... AS s_p2, ... AS s_typ FROM source_table) s 

ON (t.p1 = s.s_p1 
    AND t.p2 = s.s_p2 
    AND t.typ = s.s_typ)

WHEN NOT MATCHED 
THEN 
   INSERT (obj_id, 
           p1, 
           p2, 
           typ) 
   VALUES (s_main_obj_id, 
           s_p1, 
           s_p2, 
           s_typ)
```

I get:

> 1. 00000 -  "unique constraint (%s.%s) violated"
>
> *Cause:    An UPDATE or INSERT statement attempted to insert a duplicate key.

The ID of the constraint points to the target table's obj_id.

The **s_main_obj_id** that is generated in the SELECT within USING is definitely unique; I have tried taking the SELECT and joining the result with the target table on the PK obj_id:

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT  ... AS s_main_obj_id, ... AS s_p1, 
            ... AS s_p2, ... AS s_typ FROM source_table) s
JOIN target_table t 
ON (t.obj_id = s.s_main_obj_id)
```

This gives me 0 results.

How can the MERGE be trying to insert a duplicate key if this gives no results?

EDIT: On the target table, I have the following constraints:
[image]

(the error mentions the SYS_C00138978 constraint)

And the following index:

[image]

And here is the create table statement:

```
CREATE TABLE TARGET_TABLE_NAME
(
  OBJ_ID VARCHAR2(40 CHAR) NOT NULL 
, TYP VARCHAR2(1 CHAR) 
, P1 VARCHAR2(40 CHAR) 
, P2 VARCHAR2(40 CHAR) 
, CONSTRAINT SYS_C00138978 PRIMARY KEY 
  (
    OBJ_ID 
  )
  ENABLE 
) 
LOGGING 
TABLESPACE "USERS" 
PCTFREE 10 
INITRANS 1 
STORAGE 
( 
  INITIAL 65536 
  NEXT 1048576 
  MINEXTENTS 1 
  MAXEXTENTS 2147483645 
  BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT 
);

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX TARGET_TABLE_NAME_OBJ_ID ON TARGET_TABLE_NAME (OBJ_ID ASC) 
LOGGING 
TABLESPACE "USERS" 
PCTFREE 10 
INITRANS 2 
STORAGE 
( 
  INITIAL 65536 
  NEXT 1048576 
  MINEXTENTS 1 
  MAXEXTENTS 2147483645 
  BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT 
);
```

Comment: Maybe there is an additional unique constraint defined (other than the PK). Please show us the complete CREATE TABLE statement and all defined indexes.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Added screenshots of the constraint and index on the table, I'll post the create table statement after I anonymize it.

Comment: What is the datatype of `obj_id`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name obj_id is a VARCHAR2

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Added the table creation statement.

Comment: Any empty strings `''` involved in your "constant" data?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name What do you mean by constant?

Comment: @Laurence If you mean adding t.obj_id = s.s_main_obj_id to the condition in the ON of the MERGE, it gives me the same error as before.

Comment: Is there a reason why this is a MERGE rather than an INSERT with a correlated subquery to check for record existence?

Comment: @David Aldridge Only that I've mostly seen MERGE as the "recommended way". Maybe it would be easier to do it as you suggest, I'll have to look into it.

Comment: OK, well if you don't need the update or delete clauses then I'd keep it as simple and conventional as possible -- ie. an insert.

Comment: My guess would be that the query you're USING to insert the rows returns duplicate primary key values - have you checked that?

Comment: @Frank Schmitt Running that select vs. running the select with "distinct" gives me the same number of results.

Comment: My guess would be that they differ in the non-primary key columns; did you check the distinct values only for the primary key?

Comment: @Frank Schmitt Sorry, you were right -- the USING select did indeed return some duplicates (some funny uuids built on the fly which I thought were unique). Thanks for the suggestion, it did put me on the right track!